# QGIS - Value Relation Widget problem

Tags: qgis, widget

I have problem with Value Relation Widget and current_value filter expression when select more then one features to change attribute with multi edit tool in all new QGIS version after ca. 3.22.7 v.

I send this problem to GITHUB  but after 4 month nothing hapend

There is image with my value relation and filter expression setup.

[image]

On QGIS 3.22.7 and older version everything is ok, when select one features or multiple features  and use multi edit tool from Digitizing toolbar,  drop down menu is with all data and current_value expression work ok.

[image]

On later version 3.24 - 3.28. 3.30 when select one features it works but if i want change multiple data , select multiple features and use multi edit tool from Digitizing toolbar, drop down menu is empty.

[image]

If i try the same thing but use multiple edit tool in attribute table then drop down menu have data but always the same data so then filter expression does not work.

[image]
[image]

Maybe newer QGIS version have some changes with value relation widget and I do something wrong or problem is bug.

Does anyone have a similar problem ?